# How to display data in Table cell in tableview in ios using Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I want to display data in table view cell. In first view Controller, I displayed a view controller and then user select the contacts. The selected contacts displayed in table format along with money. so those contacts name and money passed to next controller. In Next controller, I took the table view and table cell. But my problem is the selected contacts and money displayed in the console but the data is not attached to a cell. I tried so much but it doesn't display data in the cell. My nextController  is:

```
import UIKit
import Contacts
class ContactViewController:UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var amount: UILabel!
}

class Contacts:UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    var b:[String] = []
    var c:[String] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource=self
        tableView.delegate=self
        print("money for each contact\(c)")

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return b.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Contacts", for: indexPath)as! ContactViewController
        let con = b[indexPath.row]
        cell.name.text = con
        cell.amount.text=c[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

}
}
```

Comment: what the result you get here `print("money for each contact\(c)")`

Comment: it prints money in array

Comment: save in array and reload your table

Comment: try printing out the array    b

Comment: array b displays names of the selected contacts.

Comment: print something in the cellForRowAt and check whether it gets printed

Answer (score 0):

Use array of tuples for storing contacts and money:

```
var data: [(contact: String, money: String)]
```

Add `tableView.reloadData()` after assigning new data to `data`:

```
var data: [(contact: String, money: String)] {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

If data is assigning in `prepare(for segue: sender:)` than add `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check "Contacts" is the cell identifier from Storyboard. You need to add init method on cell class.

```
class ContactViewController:UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var amount: UILabel!

init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

}
```

Another one, You need to add `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method and return the height of the cell.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
      return 44 // OR UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yes "Contacts" is cell identifier.

Comment: is `cellForRowAt` is calling or not?

Comment: yes it is calling. I place the statement to print b in cellForRowAt function . The b value is printed

Comment: No it's not working.:(. After selecting contacts it doesn't go to another controller that means to table view

Comment: Are you set `tableview` delegate and `dataSource` from storyboard?
Please follow this tutorial and check is anything missing on your code. https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/

Comment: yaa i set all those in story board

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164731/discussion-between-faysal-ahmed-and-vijju).